# Securing Jersey RESTful services with spring-security-core using jaxrs plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, jersey, jax-rs

I'm needing to implement some RESTful webservices for a client in a Grails app and I want to use the jaxrs plugin but I am having a heck of a time finding information on how to implement security that isn't realm based (tomcat-users.xml).  I am using the spring-security-core plugin and I'd like to utilize it to authenticate against my webservices.  How do I send credentials to the webservice and then authenticate those using spring security?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following and used a modified version of the solution to solve my problem

http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html